# if $f=f(x,y)$ where $x=u^2 - v^2$ and $y = \frac{u}{v}$ what is $f_{uu}$ and $f_{vv}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have tried to calculate this question and am not sure about my process being correct.  If you have the time, can you tell me if my answer is correct or not and if not where I have made my mistake(s).  Thanks in advance.

$$
 \begin{align*}
  f &= f(x.y), x = u^2 - v^2, y = \frac{u}{v}\\
  &\text{find $f_{uu}$ and $f_{vv}$}\\
  \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} &= 2u\\
  \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} &= -2v\\
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} &= \frac{1}{v}\\
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} &= -\frac{u}{v^2}\\
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\\
  &=2u\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) + \frac{1}{v}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(f\right) &= 2u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( f \right) + \frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( f \right) \tag{1} \label{equation0}\\
  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} &= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right)\\
  &=2\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) + 2u\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) 
  + \frac{1}{v}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \tag{2} \label {equation1}\\
  &\text{Use equation $\eqref{equation0}$ to find $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)$ and 
   $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)$.}\\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)
  &= 2u\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) + 
  \frac{1}{v} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) \\
  &= 2u\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{v} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} \tag{3} \label{equation2} \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)
  &= 2u \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) + 
  \frac{1}{v} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \\
  &= 2u \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{1}{v} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \tag{4} \label{equation3} \\  
  &\text{Substitute $\eqref{equation2}$ and $\eqref{equation3}$ into $\eqref{equation1}$.}\\
  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} &= 2 \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) + 2u \left(2u \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{v} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}\right) + \frac{1}{v} \left(2u \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{1}{v} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)\\
  &= 2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + 4u^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{2u}{v} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} + \frac{2u}{v} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}
  + \frac{1}{v^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\\
  &\text{Assuming $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$}\\
  &= 2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + 4u^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{4u}{v} \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} \right) + \frac{1}{v^2} \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)\\
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} 
  &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\\
  &=-2v\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) - \frac{u}{v^2} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(f\right) &= -2v \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( f \right) -  \frac{u}{v^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( f \right) \tag{5} \label{equation4}\\
  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2} &= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)\\
  &=-2\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) - 2v \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) + \frac{2u}{v^3}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) - \\
  & \frac{u}{v^2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \tag{6} \label {equation5}\\
  &\text{Use equation $\eqref{equation4}$ to find $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)$.}\\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)
  &= -2v \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) - 
  \frac{u}{v^2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) \\
  &= -2v \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} - \frac{u}{v^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} \tag{7} \label{equation6} \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)
  &= -2v \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) - 
  \frac{u}{v^2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \\
  &= -2v \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} - \frac{u}{v^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \tag{8} \label{equation7} \\  
  &\text{Substitute $\eqref{equation6}$ and $\eqref{equation7}$ into $\eqref{equation5}$.}\\
  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2} &= -2 \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) - 2v \left(-2v \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} - \frac{u}{v^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}\right) +
  \frac{2u}{v^3} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \\
  &- \frac{u}{v^2} \left(-2v \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} - \frac{u}{v^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)\\
  &= -2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + 4v^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{2u}{v} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} - \frac{2u}{v^3} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{2u}{v} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \\
  &+ \frac{u^2}{v^4} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\\
  &\text{Assuming $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$}\\
  &= -2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + 4v^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} - \frac{4u}{v} \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}\right) +\frac{2u}{v^3} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) +  \frac{u^2}{v^4} \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)\\
 \end{align*}
$$

Comment: I checked $\;f_{uu}\;$ . It is correct. If you worked the other derivatives as nicely as this one then you're fine.

Comment: Thank you for your time and calculating $f_{uu}$ for me @DonAntonio.  I'll mark this as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is faster to use subscript notation.
$$f_u=f_x u_x+f_y y_u=2uf_x+\frac{1}{v}f_y$$
Taking the derivative of the last expression again wrt. u,
$$f_{uu}=2f_x+2u(2uf_{xx}+\frac{1}{v}f_{xy})+\frac{1}{v}(2uf_{xy}+\frac{1}{v}f_{yy})$$
$$f_{uu}=2f_x+4u^2f_{xx}+\frac{4u}{v}f_{xy}+\frac{1}{v^2}f_{yy}$$
You did it correct.
Similarly,
$$f_v=f_x x_v+f_y y_v=-2vf_x-\frac{u}{v^2}f_y$$
Taking the derivative of the last expression again wrt. v,
$$f_{vv}=-2f_x-2v(f_{xx}x_v+f_{xy}y_v)+\frac{2u}{v^3}f_y-\frac{u}{v^2}(f_{xy}x_v+f_{yy}y_v)$$
$$f_{vv}=-2f_x+\frac{2u}{v^3}f_y-2v(f_{xx}(-2v)+f_{xy}(-\frac{u}{v^2}))-\frac{u}{v^2}(f_{xy}(-2v)+f_{yy}(-\frac{u}{v^2}))$$
$$f_{vv}=-2f_x+\frac{2u}{v^3}f_y+4v^2f_{xx}+\frac{4u}{v}f_{xy}+\frac{u^2}{v^4}f_{yy}$$
One term is different. Yours is $-\frac{4u}{v}f_{xy}$, mine is $+\frac{4u}{v}f_{xy}$. I guess mine is correct. But, we can never be %100 sure in math.